# Why my edit text is not taking gravity...?

Tags: android, android-edittext, gravity

I am adding one edit text pro-grammatically, in that i am setting the gravity but its not reflecting.

[image]

code:

```
EditText bcc = new EditText(getApplicationContext());
        LayoutParams para = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, 45);
        //bcc.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#00000000"));
        bcc.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#000000"));
        bcc.setSingleLine(true);
        para.setMargins(0, 0, 0, 5); // left, top, right, bottom.       
        bcc.setTextSize(15);
        bcc.setGravity(Gravity.BOTTOM);
        bcc.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_EMAIL_ADDRESS);
        bcc.setId(100);
        bcc.setLayoutParams(para);
```

Comment: why are you attributes in the code? cant you do it in xml?

Comment: its a dynamic content added only on some specific condition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eventually you would be adding this EditText `bcc` to a view group? Depending on what type of ViewGroup the parent is, you would need to do the following:

**LinearLayout:**

via XML: 
You have to set android:layout_gravity="center_vertical".

via code:

```
LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp = viewGroup.getLayoutParams();
lp.gravity = Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL;
viewGroup.setLayoutParams(lp);
```

The code will be different for different parent layout types.

Answer (score 1):

This gravity `bcc.setGravity(Gravity.BOTTOM);` marks only how text should lay inside `EditText`.

If parent of EditText is `RelativeLayout` you can provide rules inside `RelativeLayout.LayoutParams`.

Answer (score 1):

**set gravity of parent of the view**. If view parent is layout then the code will be like the following

```
((LinearLayout) bcc.getParent()).setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL);
```

Answer (score 0):

When you creating EditText programmatically, you must at first set setKeyListener(TextKeyListener.getInstance());

Otherwise your view will always be aligned with Gravity.TOP.

I don't know real reason, but before you specifiy any other parameter to EditText, you must set setKeyListener(TextKeyListener.getInstance());

**Correction : It only work if you create you custom widget by extending  EditText and defining your widget in XML. Only tested on Android 5.0.1**